# How can I do that my Rover goes to the Left after doing a photo

Tags: arduino, esp32

at the moment I'm trying that my Rovers drives until he found an Object. Then he should go to the right, stops and making a photo. After this first tour, the Rover should drive around the object and should always make a photo. 
The problem is that he goes first to the right but drives always forward without driving around.

I already ask in this group for help that he only moves and drives around but I would try for myself that he drives around but without success.

Here you can see my Arduino Code that I am using.

```
// Define SensorS pins
#define trigPin 15
#define echoPin 2

//Define SensorXL pins
#define trigPinXL 14
#define echoPinXL 13

//Define Raspberry Pin
#define RaspiPin 26

//Define Motor pins
#define motorIn3 16 //Input 3
#define motorIn1 17 //Input 1
#define motorIn4 18 //Input 4
#define motorIn2 19 //Input 2

// Defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

// Define ActivateDistance
const int activateDistance = 40;
const int activateDistance2 =40;

void setup()
{
    // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(trigPinXL, OUTPUT);
    // Sets the echoPin as an Input
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(echoPinXL, INPUT);
    // sets the Motorpins  as outputs:
    pinMode(motorIn1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn4, OUTPUT);
    //Sets Raspberry Pin as output
    pinMode(RaspiPin, OUTPUT);
    // Starts the serial communication
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void stop()
{
    // stop motor without duration
    Serial.println("STOP");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
}

void stopp(int duration)
{
    // stop motor without duration
    Serial.println("STOP");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void left(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes to left
    Serial.println("LEFT");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void right(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes to left
    Serial.println("RIGHT");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void forward(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes forward
    Serial.println("FORWARD");
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

long get_distance(void)
{
    //get distance from sensor
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    return distance;
}

long get_distanceXL(void)
{
    //get distance from sensor
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPinXL, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    return distance;
}

int turn = 0;
void loop()
{
    //Define Raspi Pin as Low
    digitalWrite(RaspiPin, LOW);
    // check sensor
    if (get_distance() <= activateDistance)
    {
        // go right for 1 second
        right(1000);
        //stop for 2 seconds
        stopp(2000);
        //make a Photo
        digitalWrite(RaspiPin, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(RaspiPin, LOW);
        while(turn<4)
        {
          if(get_distanceXL()>activateDistance2)
          {
            //go left for 1 second
            left(1000);
            forward(1000);
            stopp(2000);
            digitalWrite(RaspiPin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(RaspiPin, LOW);
            forward(500);
            turn = turn + 1;                                      
          }
          else
            //go forward for 1 second
            forward(500);
            stopp(2000);
            digitalWrite(RaspiPin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(RaspiPin, LOW);
            forward(500);
        }
    }

    else
        // go forward for 1 second
        forward(1000);
}
```

Comment: Why you using two `get_distance()`? You can just check the distance and then make a turn. I'm not sure why you check 4 times for `get_distanceXL()>activateDistance2`?

Comment: I'm using two get_distance() because I've two differnet sensor.  The first only look if an object is in front of him and the other makes, that the rover drives around the detected objecr